# How to format data for use in nntool (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, formatting, neural-network, nntool

In `nntool`, the sample data is formatted as: `[0 1 -1; 2 3 1]`

I have ~8000 data points in a text file. 
**How do I format those points for use here? What does the semicolon signify?**

Comment: What does your 8000 points data look like?

Comment: it is a simple text file with 8000 space separated float values.

Comment: yes but which is input/output, and how many dimensions if any, and so on. You asked how to format the data to use with nntool, but you didnt describe your data..

Comment: @Amro, you probably read from the other ques, my data is like this: `in = [5 columns of data-points]; out = [1 column of data-points];`

Comment: I guess this is settled then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/nnet/getting4.html#35958), that would mean each column of the input data would be separated by a `;`. The `Target` data would be a vector like `[1 2 3 4]` corresponding to each row of the input data.

E.g. if you want to learn the XOR truth table:

```
X Y XOR
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

Then the `Input` matrix is

```
X Y 
0 0 
0 1 
1 0 
1 1
```

And the `Target` is

```
XOR
0
1
1
0
```

And therefore, your data should be formatted as `[0 0 1 1;0 1 0 1]` for the input (each column is separated by a `;`) and the target data would be `[0 1 1 0]`.

As far as your 8000 point data file is concerned, you can load it into a variable in your workspace and let `nntool` read the input matrix from your workspace or a `.mat` file (after you've saved the variable into it).